# Stop Updating Locations on ios when user clicks stop button

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactjs, react-native, cllocationmanager

I am using location services in my ios app for tracking purposes. The app tracks location in foreground as well as background, until the app terminates.

Here all the code is written in react-native java script except the beacon tracking API values which are being sent from native ios code through app delegate and location manager.

The app updates locations in all cases throughout the life cycle of app but sends beacon values to API only after a specific track interval. There is a stop button, on clicking of which the app stops sending location values to API but the location manager still continues to change lat long values.

What i want is, the clicking of stop button should stop the location manager updates and should start only when i click on 'start' button. This can be handled through app delegate methods but they are called only when any app transition happens like switching from foreground to background or vice versa.

They are not called if i switch between screens remaining on foreground only. And all the screens are handled through react code only, not in native ios.

Suggest something to control the location manager activities in the manner mentioned above, please.

Comment: You should have two button action methods like: `-startButton:` and `-stopButton:`. You might already have your location manager initialized in your code somewhere. Save the reference to that location manager. And then inside your start button action `[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation]` and in stop button action `[self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation]`.

Comment: @nayem yes, but as i said all screens and button actions are handled on react-native code not in my objective c code, so i cannot have button action methods in ios specific code. My code only has a app delegate class of its own thats it. The rest is react code which is linked to my code, for location updates only